# How do I know if call to server was triggered by a callback?

Tags: asp.net, callback

I'm calling a page via [WebForm_DoCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163878.aspx#S2) javascript function.  On server, in Page_Load I'm trying to check if this is a callback by checking [Page.IsCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.iscallback.aspx) flag.  However, this flag is false. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need

```
ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).IsInAsyncPostBack
```